# Is there a way to let the computer check for combinations in a list

Tags: python

im trying to code the game Yathzee in python and I have ran into some problems, this is my code so far.

```
import random

score = 0
dice = []
for d in range(5):
    dice.append(random.randint(1,6))

def throw():
    print('you rolled: ', end='')
    for d in dice:
        print(str(d) + ' ', end='')

throw()

print('Do you want to roll again?')
ja = int(input('Enter 1 to throw again, if you want to stop enter 2.'))

if ja == 1 :
    reroll = input('what dice do you want to reroll?')
    reroll = reroll.split()
    for index, ch in enumerate(reroll):
        reroll[index] = int(ch) - 1
    for index in reroll:
        dice[index] = random.randint(1,6)
    throw()


elif ja == 2:
    #this is where i need to check if there is scored yes or no
```

I want to implement Yathzee's game rules but I don't know how to make the computer check if there has been a combination worth points.
for instance:
you roll: [3 , 5 , 2 , 5 , 5] this is a three of a kind, = 3+5+2+5+5 = 20 points.
How do i code this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by combinations. Are you looking for the ``sum`` of a list's elements?

Comment: wouldnt that be 15 points since `5+5+5=15`??

Comment: you could make a dictionary counting each element in your list like so: `dct = {i:lst.count(i) for i in lst}` (with `lst = [3,5,2,5,5]`)

Comment: @oskros ``collections.Counter`` is much more appropriate for that.

Comment: inspiration here: https://betterprogramming.pub/interview-questions-write-yahtzee-in-python-72695550d84e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function for this rule and other rules.

```
# rolls of the dice
rolls = [3 , 5 , 2 , 5 , 5]

# make a dict that counts the list items.
dct = {i:rolls.count(i) for i in rolls}

for k,v in dct.items():
    if v ==4:
        # four of a kind (quads)
        print('got four of this:', k)

    if v ==3:
        # three of a kind
        print('got three of this:', k)

    if v ==2:
        # a pair
        print('got a pair of this:', k)
```

the result:

```
got three of this: 5
```

There are other methods too, but this is quite simple to implement and works.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to anwser. It really helped

Comment: you are elcome.  you can also add other rules (such as a full house = 3 + 2). Please do upvote this answer.